# Where is the best place to put Terms & Conditions in a sign-up flow?

Tags: user-behavior, android, ios, mobile-application, user-expectation

I am creating an app that when the user taps a certain action button such as "Follow" they are taken through the login flow.

Included in the login flow is

1) Asking for Facebook permission 
2) Creating a profile (Name, Picture, Email, Phone) 
3) Accepting Terms & Conditions

We need to actually show the T&C's for legal purposes so we can't have the "By creating a profile you are accepting our Terms & Conditions" format.

I was hoping to get some answers or statistics on whether placing it before or after "Create a profile" would be a better experience for the user or a higher conversion rate of accepting the T&C's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I strongly recommend that you put the T&C first, followed by the Facebook agreement, followed by the account creation. This is the most logical flow because the end user will want to know there rights above anything, and know how their personal information will be handled, with creating an account being the least important step.

Answer (score 1):

The best option for T&C is use a check box with the link to TC, only when the check box is selected you can go to the next step.

Another alternative is to show the T&C and have the Agree or Not agree with the display.

Answer (score 0):

I think i would say the obvious: the common patter for that now is

[] I agree to the {Company Name} Terms and Conditions

[] I accept the terms and conditions.

where [] is a checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is somewhat debatable. if they are agreeing to your Facebook sign in and you get the permissions, what happens if they decline the t&c?

I would question if in this case and t&c should be the first thing that is shown to the user followed by account creation/facebook permission request.

I would also like to know in what way you're planning to present the user with the t&c and how long it is. (This can help us helping you).